# Elastic count by facets that exists only for some documents

Tags: elasticsearch, partial, facet

I have a facet that exists only in some of the documents. I wish to know how many documents have each possible value of the facet, and how many doesn't have this facet at all.
The facet is color. My current query returns the count for different colors, but doesn't returns the count for documents without color:

```
"facets": {
      "_Properties": {
          "terms": {
             "field": "Color",
             "size": 100
          }
      } 
   }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Facets have been [deprecated](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets.html#search-facets) in Elasticsearch. You can use a combination of [Terms Aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and [Missing Aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-missing-aggregation.html) for this. Find the query below for your requirement:

```
"aggs": {
    "_Properties": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "Color",
            "size": 100
        }
    },
    "_MissingColor": {
        "missing": {
            "field": "Color"
        }
    }
}
```